# 19 digit prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers, puzzle

I am searching for a particular type of prime number.

It is of 19 digit.If I removew unit place it will reduce to an 18 digit prime number.
If I again remove digit from unit place it will become 17 digit prime number..and so on...
What I obtained is each place except first one cannot be filled by even number and $5$. First digit can be filled by $2,3,5$,and $7$
So there are $4.18^4=274877906944$ possible numbers.
sum of digits should not be  a multiple of $3$..
How to proceed ?

Comment: Do you know that such a number exists?

Comment: If you *replace* a digit in a 19-digit number, it will still be a 19-digit number, not an 18-digit number. Do you perhaps mean "remove"? But if so, what is with the comments about what the digit can be replaced with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence [A024770](https://oeis.org/A024770) in the OEIS has the full list of what are called right-truncatable primes. You can see in the b-file
https://oeis.org/A024785/b024785.txt
that none have 19 digits.

Comment: There was a major problem in my question... As per the question it was right truncated prime....But right truncated primes have maximum length 8 digits...It has to be a left truncated prime...Thanks for reference....

Comment: @Madhu: Yes, actually I was confused for just that reason -- you can see the left-truncatable ones in the history, or just search for them in the OEIS.